# How to control primefaces default component size

Tags: css, primefaces

i Had a issue while using `p:sticky` for `p:panel` and i have fixed the width size for `p:panel`.

**That code:**

```
<p:panel id="scrollTopId" style="height: 21px; position:static; top: auto; width:99.4%;">......</p:panel>

<p:sticky target="scrollTopId"/>
```

After loading my page the `<p:panel>` had `width:99.4%` but when i scroll then the `p:panel` reach top and automatically its width size getting high than my `width:99.4%`.

**Like:**

```
element.style 
{
    height: 21px;
    position: static;
    top: auto;
    width: 1290.17px;
    z-index: 1005;
}
```

Any idea to fix the width as what i gave the width:99.4%?

Answer (score 0):

It takes 99.4% of the width of the parent container, but that is also dependend on the value of the value of the css position. So if either changes due to it being sticky on top, you can see this behaviour.

Use a browser it developer tool like firebug to see what actually changes and where it originates from.

I'm afraid you have to do some advanced css to get it to behave as you want (this is in fact not a PF issue)